# How to save Coordinates to firebase Geofire realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm quite new to Geofire and Firease in general and I'm trying to save Location LatLng values to a firebase geofire database but its not working. 
I'm trying to do it under onLocationChanged() but on running my app, firebase remains empty;

[Here is the **photo** of my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDM68.png)

[image]

And here is the **code** that I have used to try save the latLng values to the database.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //Getting identifier
    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Email");

    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(reference);
    geoFire.setLocation(userID,new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));

}
```

Please help.

Also here is my **Logcat**;

```
2018-11-22 10:22:22.865 20312-20423/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2018-11-22 10:22:23.607 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:23.607 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:24.164 20312-20491/? E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
2018-11-22 10:22:24.607 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:24.607 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:25.609 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:25.609 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:26.610 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:26.610 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:27.611 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:27.611 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:28.613 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:28.614 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:29.566 920-1924/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
2018-11-22 10:22:29.566 920-1924/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(66667000)m, error(0), index(2)
2018-11-22 10:22:29.614 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:29.614 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:29.686 920-14520/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
2018-11-22 10:22:29.686 920-14520/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(200000000)m, error(0), index(2)
2018-11-22 10:22:30.615 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:30.615 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:31.616 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:31.616 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:22:32.616 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:22:32.616 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:06.726 21109-21109/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.opera.minisettingsmocker
2018-11-22 10:23:07.185 21109-21109/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2018-11-22 10:23:07.486 21109-21109/? E/EventDispatcher: Error when unregistering event handler
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing event handler for an annotated method. Is class eac registered?
        at cyf.d(OperaSrc:3294)
        at dzw.a(OperaSrc:4080)
        at dzs.a(OperaSrc:76)
        at dzs.<init>(OperaSrc:62)
        at com.opera.android.OperaMiniApplication.onCreate(OperaSrc:9048)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5503)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
2018-11-22 10:23:07.675 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:07.676 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:08.267 21159-21159/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.appmanager
2018-11-22 10:23:08.575 21159-21175/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2018-11-22 10:23:08.678 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:08.678 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:08.919 21159-21206/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.appmanager.oxygen.nekodirect.progress
2018-11-22 10:23:09.679 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:09.679 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:09.932 21217-21283/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2018-11-22 10:23:10.104 21217-21289/? E/[Analytics]:: AnalyticsSdk is not exist!
2018-11-22 10:23:10.212 920-1103/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=383, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
2018-11-22 10:23:10.214 920-1103/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=384, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
2018-11-22 10:23:10.612 20796-20796/? E/DX-Toolbox: {main}[y] license should not null
2018-11-22 10:23:10.680 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:10.680 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:11.375 21217-21217/? E/cr_VariationsSeedLoader: Failed loading variations seed. Variations disabled.
2018-11-22 10:23:11.680 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:11.680 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:11.739 21217-21340/? E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
2018-11-22 10:23:12.681 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:12.681 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:13.264 920-19002/? E/ActivityManager: isAllowedAutoStartApp pkgName=com.proxyfree.ultimate.vpn
2018-11-22 10:23:13.264 20287-20862/? E/NetworkScheduler.TED: Couldn't start service: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY cmp=com.proxyfree.ultimate.vpn/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver (has extras) }
2018-11-22 10:23:13.286 20287-19914/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unknown result code received: 4
2018-11-22 10:23:13.682 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:13.682 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:14.624 21424-21424/? E/ACRA: Skipping ANR Detector for process: com.instagram.android:videoplayer
2018-11-22 10:23:14.683 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:14.683 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:15.340 920-1099/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
2018-11-22 10:23:15.343 920-1101/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
2018-11-22 10:23:15.684 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:15.684 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:15.918 920-920/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
2018-11-22 10:23:15.939 920-18889/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast message_notify_action_now from system 1953:com.transsion.smartcover/1000 pkg com.transsion.smartcover
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19298)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19947)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:502)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3063)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
2018-11-22 10:23:16.685 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:16.685 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:17.686 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:17.686 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:18.688 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:18.688 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:19.689 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:19.690 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:20.112 21217-21217/? E/HttpUtil: startService
2018-11-22 10:23:20.121 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onCreate
2018-11-22 10:23:20.126 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onStartCommand
2018-11-22 10:23:20.126 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onStart
2018-11-22 10:23:20.126 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onStart, action: anative.action.setup.alarm
2018-11-22 10:23:20.127 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadWrapper:: IntentService setupAlarm
2018-11-22 10:23:20.167 21217-21469/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onHandleIntent: 
2018-11-22 10:23:20.184 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onDestroy
2018-11-22 10:23:20.281 920-6458/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
2018-11-22 10:23:20.281 920-6458/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000)m, error(0), index(2)
2018-11-22 10:23:20.690 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:20.690 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:21.379 920-1099/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
2018-11-22 10:23:21.391 920-1101/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
2018-11-22 10:23:21.529 920-6458/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast message_notify_action_now from system 1953:com.transsion.smartcover/1000 pkg com.transsion.smartcover
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19298)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19947)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:502)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3063)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
2018-11-22 10:23:21.537 920-920/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
2018-11-22 10:23:21.691 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:21.691 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:22.694 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:22.694 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:22.843 1789-1801/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:22.844 1789-1801/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:22.909 920-941/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2018-11-22 10:23:22.909 920-941/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2018-11-22 10:23:22.939 920-941/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-11-22 10:23:23.672 920-6463/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
2018-11-22 10:23:23.672 920-6463/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(200000000)m, error(0), index(2)
2018-11-22 10:23:23.695 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:23.695 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:24.696 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:24.696 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:25.697 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:25.697 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:25.844 1789-1801/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:26.101 1789-1801/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:26.101 1789-1801/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:26.698 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:26.698 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:27.511 920-1099/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
2018-11-22 10:23:27.515 920-1101/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
2018-11-22 10:23:27.699 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:27.699 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:28.700 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:28.700 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:29.101 1789-1801/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:29.703 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:29.703 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:30.705 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:30.705 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:31.243 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onCreate
2018-11-22 10:23:31.243 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onStartCommand
2018-11-22 10:23:31.243 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onStart
2018-11-22 10:23:31.243 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onStart, action: anative.action.refresh.cache
2018-11-22 10:23:31.243 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadWrapper:: IntentService handlePreloadBackground
2018-11-22 10:23:31.244 21217-21501/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onHandleIntent: 
2018-11-22 10:23:31.254 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadWrapper:: networktype: 0, interval: 24500697
2018-11-22 10:23:31.255 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadWrapper:: IntentService handleReportNoticeBackground
2018-11-22 10:23:31.260 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadWrapper:: IntentService handleReportGpBackground
2018-11-22 10:23:31.262 21217-21217/? E/AdPreloadService:: IntentService onDestroy
2018-11-22 10:23:31.707 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:31.707 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:31.767 920-920/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
2018-11-22 10:23:31.781 920-16410/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast message_notify_action_now from system 1953:com.transsion.smartcover/1000 pkg com.transsion.smartcover
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19298)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19947)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:502)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3063)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
2018-11-22 10:23:32.556 920-1099/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
2018-11-22 10:23:32.569 920-1101/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
2018-11-22 10:23:32.707 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:32.707 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:33.708 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:33.708 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:34.709 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:34.709 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:35.348 920-920/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
2018-11-22 10:23:35.356 920-1944/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast message_notify_action_now from system 1953:com.transsion.smartcover/1000 pkg com.transsion.smartcover
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19298)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19947)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:502)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3063)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
2018-11-22 10:23:35.709 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:35.709 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:36.710 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:36.710 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:37.711 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:37.711 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:38.713 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:38.713 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:38.718 920-1099/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
2018-11-22 10:23:38.768 920-1101/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
2018-11-22 10:23:38.787 11248-21510/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
2018-11-22 10:23:39.714 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:39.714 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:40.716 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:40.716 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:41.718 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:41.718 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:42.719 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:42.719 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:43.721 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:43.721 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:44.722 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:44.723 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:44.996 920-1099/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
2018-11-22 10:23:45.007 920-1101/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
2018-11-22 10:23:45.723 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:45.723 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:46.615 920-935/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast message_notify_action_now from system 1953:com.transsion.smartcover/1000 pkg com.transsion.smartcover
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19298)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19947)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:502)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3063)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
2018-11-22 10:23:46.626 920-920/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
2018-11-22 10:23:46.724 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:46.724 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
2018-11-22 10:23:47.725 1789-1802/? E/GED: Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
2018-11-22 10:23:47.725 1789-1802/? E/GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
```

Comment: Is there some error you're getting in logcat? Can you check what is shown in your logcat?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I've updated it. Please have a look.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit However, the Logcat doesn't show any error reference to any of my classes.